# Stopping browser from sending automated AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, browser

I am using one of the web application that my friend has made. The webpage automatically make AJAX calls after a regular interval (say 1 second). I want my browser "Chrome" to stop this behaviour and rather let me make AJAX calls manually via Advanced Rest Client Application in Google chrome extensions.

Update 1 : I do not have the administrative access to change the website source code of the web application. I just want to send requests manually to  that webapp instead of the underlying javascript or whatever to do that after regular intervals.

Actually I need a kind of filter that capture all the XHR requests and then show them to me, allow me to tweak them and then allow sending it to the server.

Is this possible to do so in Chrome ?

If its not possible, any other browser you would like to suggest where it is possible to do so ?

Comment: I don't understand. Why not just change the web page's source code?

Comment: just assume that i can't change the website source code, i don't have the administrative access.

Comment: which file is called in your application using ajax

Comment: and for your calling via ajax send session id and check that on your file

Comment: AJAX makes a POST request to the server. i want to modify this request as soon as its made before sent to the server

Comment: perhaps i think i found the answer , this gonna help me i guess. but still more answers are welcome if anybody has : http://netsecurity.about.com/od/hackertools/a/What-Hackers-Do-Not-Want-You-To-Know-About-The-Tamper-Data-Firefox-Add-on.htm

Answer (score 1):

Chrome comes with [Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/).

If you look at the network tab, you'll see the request being made. You can then see where in the code the request is being made. You can access that Javascript that is loaded locally and modify the timing between the AJAX calls. However, this will only be done on a one time basis as once you refresh the browser your change will be gone. The only way to make the change permanent is to change the source code on the server.